# WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 - Passing XML data as string in a payloadfactory with media type as JSON

Tags: json, xml, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 ESB 4.8.1 component, for a scenario where I would like to attach the XML data as a string in payloadfactory with mediatype as JSON. I tried below scenario but the data is converting to json data. Please help me how I can resolve this issue and send the XML data as string.
Ex :

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
   <format>
     "original_data":"${symbol.dollar}1",
   </format>
   <args>
     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="${symbol.dollar}ctx:original_data" />
   </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a string function like concat and add a string to break formatting back to json. Something like this

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>
            {
              "original_data" : "$1",
            } 
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="fn:concat('Payload: ', get-property('your_payload'))"/>
        </args>
</payloadFactory>
```